# Type mismatch error in vba using activecell

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an error which is type mismatch.. i am trying to set up active cell equal to certain cell. If activecell = **`E4:E18`** then do this here is my code can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong in here.

```
        If ActiveCell.Row = Range(Cells(4, 5), Cells(18, 5)) Then
              ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4) = Now
        If ActiveCell.Row = Range(Cells(4, 8), Cells(18, 8)) Then
              ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 7) = Now
```

Which is I'm trying to set up active **`cell = E4 to E18`** then this
'

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to compare a number `ActiveCell.Row` against a range object which is what the `Range` method returns. You would need to use this:

```
If ActiveCell.Row = Range(Cells(4, 5), Cells(18, 5)).Row Then
```

However, this will not work how you want it to. The `ActiveCell` is only ever a single cell, so the `Row` property is only a single number. The `Selection` range can be more than a single cell. However, the `Row` property still only returns the row number for the first row of cells.

If you are trying to check if the `ActiveCell` is within the range E4:E18, then use the `Intersect` method to see if returns a range object:

```
If Not (Intersect(ActiveCell, Range(Cells(4, 5), Cells(18, 5))) Is Nothing) Then
    MsgBox "Yes"
Else
    MsgBox "No"
End If
```

If you are just concerned with the row number, then use

```
If (ActiveCell.Row >= 4 And ActiveCell.Row <= 18) Then
    MsgBox "Yes"
Else
    MsgBox "No"
End If
```

Comment: Can you tell me why did you used intersect.. what kind of method is it ?

Comment: You should Google it.